# How to copy project dependencies using maven 1?

Tags: maven, compilation

Is there a way to copy dependencies of a project into some directory when maven 1 (not maven 2) is used as build tool?

I know that for Maven 2 there exists a dependency plugin but I cannot find one for maven 1.

What is the simplest way to copy all dependency jars to a folder?

Comment: I found uberjar plugin that wraps everything in one single JAR with a main class. Still, a "lib" directory would be a cleaner approach.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use Jelly to do that, using something like this:

```
<j:forEach var="lib" items="${pom.artifacts}">
    <ant:copy todir="${your.target.dir}" file="${lib.path}"/>
</j:forEach>
```